# Remove element in a list with condition

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have a class named Info where Info has a string type instance variable which can be accessed by `Info.getName()`

Also I have a list of instance Info such as `class_list = [Info('Aleck'), Info('John')]`.

Given a `name_list = ['Aleck', 'Bob']`, I would like to remove the element in class_list with the same name in name_list, while i also need to know if a name (such as Bob) is not in class_list (for example print out that bob is not in list)

for above example the result should be class_list = [Info('John')] and print out that bob is not on the list.

I know ugly way of doing so such as the following codes (i am not actually running it, just an example), is there elegant or Pythonic way to do this?

```
def removeElement(name_list, class_list):
    list_to_be_removed = []
    for name in name_list:
        is_name_in_list = false
        for obj in class_list
            if name == obj.getName():
                list_to_be_removed.add(obj)
                is_name_in_list = true
                break
        if is_name_in_list == false:
            print name + ' is not in the list'
        is_name_in_list = false

    for obj in list_to_be_removed:
        class_list.remove(obj)
```

Comment: I think you are confusing classes with instances.

Comment: Also, `class` is a keyword, so a bunch of that code won't run.

Comment: Sorry that I do not notice that I used a reserved word "class", modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehensions are your friend.

```
def remove_names(names_to_remove, info_list):
    return [info
            for info in info_list
            if info.getName() not in names_to_remove]
```

I changed the names of most variables to be closer to what I think you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have classes, you have class instances. `Info('Alice')` is a constructor call, that creates an instance of your Info class.

How about this:

```
filtered = [info for info in info_list if info.get_name() not in name_list]
```

Alternatively:

```
filtered = filter(lambda o: o not in name_list, info_list)
```

If you have a lot of names convert your name_list into a set and use that.

```
name_set = set(name_list)
```

Comment: I got your point, thanks very much. In your way I can have the filtered list. Then I should have another code to get the name in name_list that NOT removes anything in info_list. Really thanks.